# Concatenar strings nos parametros de uma função?

Tags: javascript

Necessito injetar o `v` como aspas simples `'v'` na concatenação do `código`

```
onClick="validaContato(1,'v') // resultado desejado no segundo parametro
```

codigo

```
 var botao =  '<div class="dropdown">'
     botao +='<a class="dropdown-item  " href="#" onClick="validaContato('+response.id+',"v");"><i class="la la-bell "></i> Valido</a>'
     botao +='<a class="dropdown-item " href="#" onClick="validaContato('+response.id+',"i");"><i class="la la-cloud-upload"></i>Inválido</a>'
     botao += '</div> </div>'
```

Comment: Podes mostrar a função `validaContato`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque não usar [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) ?

Isso simplifica-lhe bastante, pois não só é multilinha, como não tem que escapar `"` ou `'`. Para além disso você usa interpolação com `${}` ao invés de concatenar com `+`.

Ora veja:

```
var botao = 
    `<div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="validaContato(${response.id},'${v}');">
            <i class="la la-bell"></i>Valido
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick="validaContato(${response.id},'${i}');">
            <i class="la la-cloud-upload"></i>Inválido
        </a>
     </div> 
</div>`;
```

Note que mantive a estrutura, mas você tem um fecho `</div>` a mais.

Agora se quiser manter o estilo que tem basta fazer assim:

```
onClick="validaContato('+response.id+',"' + v + '")
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Isac, sanou meu problema e vou passar a utilizar as crases, bem mais tranquilo.